# How common are historical instances of mercenary armies reversing and attacking their employing country?

Tags: war

The recent events with the Wagner mercenaries, hired by the Russians to attack Ukraine and then turning around and advancing on Moscow, seem unusual.

But how unusual is this historically?

How frequently *do* mercenary armies change sides?

Comment: Read about the current civil war in Sudan.

Comment: Related: [Stories from history of mercenaries who didn't get paid](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/43533/16951)

Comment: Doesn't [Mercenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercenary) answer your question? Mercenaries attacking their employers is mentioned several times there - for example, in early modern Italy.

Comment: There are examples [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80090/what-are-the-benefits-of-not-using-private-military-companies-pmcs-as-china-di)

Comment: German guards regularly participated in overthrowing Roman emperors. But note that in the case of Wagner the mercenaries are also Russians, so one has to he careful distinguishing the country (which they pretended to defend) and the government of the country or the state.

Comment: Please note that in the Wagner case there was no change of sides. They didn't switch allegiance to Ukraine. Even "attacking their employing country" is an overstatement, it was more like a protest than a changing of sides.

Comment: See also: 30 Years War

Comment: Mercenaries aren't always employed by countries: during the Renaissance wealthy individuals, such as Cesare Borgia, hired mercenaries, and they frequently had to face rebellions from their hired troops. [Here is how](https://www.historytoday.com/archive/cesare-borgia-sinigallia) Cesare Borgia handles one such revolt, when he was aged 27.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

###### It's very historical and not at all unusual.

Mercenaries only fought when paid - and paid on time! If payment was late or absent, they stopped fighting your enemies. At best, that is. Because from that moment they started to focus on how to get paid.
Being in the business of violent enforcement and premeditated murder *(we call that 'war')*, they had ways to convince their paymaster rethink his sloppy payment policy.

In Dutch there still is a proverb: "Geen geld, geen Zwitsers" or in English: "No money, no Swiss". The Swiss were well known as excellent and courageous mercenaries, as long as they were paid on time. The moment payment was late, they went on strike.

It did happen mercenary bands changed sides, but that was bad for business. Their reputation was very important, such a band would find future employment difficult.

Marching in a threatening way to the capitol, or wherever their employer happend to be, was (and is) a way to get what they want. It did happen, for example Antwerp was unlucky enough to be pillaged twice in first the [Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sack_of_Antwerp) and later the [French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Fury) Furies. The French Fury failed. Those troops were not mercenaries, but regular troops. If regular army units pillaged a city over payment issues, you can be sure mercenary units wouldn't be any different.

[Mercenaries](https://www.history.com/news/6-legendary-mercenary-armies-from-history) are as old or nearly as old as the 'oldest profession in the world'. My answer focuses on Swiss and contemporary mercenaries, but the first mercenaries probably used their payment for services from aforementioned oldest professionals.

[Cretan archers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretan_archers) and [Balearic slingers](https://short-history.com/balearic-slingers-993b52917f44) were famous and for hire. Even older were [Nubians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nubians), employed in the [Old Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_of_ancient_Egypt#:%7E:text=Egyptian%20soldiers%20worked%20for%20pay,Dynasties%20XIX%20and%20XX%2C%20c.) in Egypt.

Carthage had a navy crewed by Carthaginians, and a (mostly) mercenary army. After the first Punic war they tried to forgo payment, which didn't sit well with the [mercenaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercenary_War).

The famous [march of the ten thousand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Thousand) was a mercenary army trying to get home after their contract became redundant.

- [Geen Geld, geen Zwitsers](https://nederlandseofficierenvereniging.nl/geen-geld-geen-zwitsers/) (Dutch)

Comment: I am German and I have never heard that "Kein Geld, keine Schweizer" proverb. That does not mean it does not exist (might be a regional thing), but it would need a better source, not just some random website.

Comment: @Jan fair enough, edited.

Comment: @Jan - as an American who learned Dutch in the 90's, that was a common enough proverb that I encountered it.

Comment: *"The famous march of the ten thousand was a mercenary army trying to get home after getting fired without payment."* That is not correct. They were not fired. Cyrus who hired them and put together the entire army was killed in battle and the army disbanded. The Greek corps held together to help each other in a hostile land.

Comment: @Jos: About the proverb; under what circumstances would you use it? Like if you were in a band and you'd been booked to play a gig but the pub-owner started whining about the price?

Comment: Ceasar's army which returned from Gaul and ended the Republic of Rome was a Mercenary Army not paid by the people of Rome but by bootie from their conquests.  It's very common, good job.

Comment: @mustermax corrected

Comment: @OscarBravo When someone hasn't the money to pay for something. He wants it, but can't have it. Your example is quite right. We'd be using 'Geen geld, geen Zwitsers!' as reply.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Machiavelli had a few words to say about relying on mercenaries, too.

Comment: While the answer provides excellent background, I wish you had more examples where mercenaries reversed and attacked the employing country, especially if the title is that it was not unusual

Comment: @OscarBravo Out of sheer curiosity: would you be that band member?

Comment: @CedricMartens The Mametines did that on Sicily. Before that, the mercenaries hired by Carthage did that, as I briefly mentioned. Often mercenaries are not employed in the employers homeland. They are hired to fight elsewhere.